# No remote Sparkclr jar found; please specify one with --remote-sparkclr-jar

Tags: c#, mobius

I am submitting an application using `sparkclr-submit` to spark standalone cluster using

```
--deploy-mode cluster
```

but it's throwing an error:

> No remote Sparkclr jar found; please specify one with `--remote-sparkclr-jar`

Which remote `sparkclr-jar` file do I need to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the repository itself of Mobius on GitHub [Microsoft/Mobius](https://github.com/Microsoft/Mobius/blob/master/notes/running-mobius-app.md) about this sparkclr-jar

i need to pass a jar file available in dependencies of that directory.

it was inside

```
runtime\dependencies\
```

and jar file was **spark-csv_2.10-1.4.0.jar**

Thanks